# If have two forms (or more). Is it possible to fetch which form has sent the upload request?

Tags: php, forms

**Form 1:**

```
<?php
echo $this->upload_message;
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="mfuploaderwp-uploadform" action="?uploadfile">
Upload file: <input name="mfuploadwp-filename" type="file">
<input class="mfuploadwp-submit" type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"></form>
```

**Form 2:**

```
<?php
echo $this->upload_message;
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="mfuploaderwp-uploadform" action="?uploadfile">
Upload file: <input name="mfuploadwp-filename" type="file">
<input class="mfuploadwp-submit" type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"></form>
```

Is it possible to fetch which form is submitted without giving any extra attributes or so to above forms? The forms are created dynamically based on what user enter for amount number of forms. (In this case user has entered 2 forms)

I want to do this so `$this->upload_message` would be accurate only for the form that is used for uploading.

Comment: Is it possible to alter names? - if so, why not just change the submit button's name value and determine what button was pressed from that?

Comment: Yes it would be possible, but then the user would have define those names and I don't want put that responsibility on the users. To clarify. Each form is created by a shortcode in wordpress, and they should be able to put those anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the name tags on your `<input type="submit">` buttons. Have one as `name="submit"` and the other as `name="submit_two"` (for example, bad naming convention), then process code as

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// do stuff
} elseif (isset($_POST['submit_two'])) {
// do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.
The cleanest way, in my opinion, is to put an hidden `input` tag in each form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="mfuploaderwp-uploadform" action="?uploadfile">
    <input type="hidden" name="active_form" value="1">
    (...)
```

and

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="mfuploaderwp-uploadform" action="?uploadfile">
    <input type="hidden" name="active_form" value="2">
    (...)
```

then, in the page that process the form, you can check it in this way:

```
if( $_POST['active_form'] == 1)
{
    (...)
}
elseif( $_POST['active_form'] == 2)
{
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Naming the buttons seems much cleaner to me

Comment: @DarkBee I have no objections. It is for that I have specified that it's my opinion. Generally I prefer to pass not-user defined parameters as hidden input, and to ignore in any case the `submit` input, also because they name/value can not be sent if the form is submitted through javascript. Anyway, I agree that your opinion has entirely sense

Answer (score 1):

If your form is generated dynamically based on the user input(The forms are created dynamically based on what user enter for amount number of forms), in this case you can use three type of solution as far as I know,

1. You can introduce a new hidden field for each form based on the form number.

Eg:

```
Upload file: <input name="mfuploadwp-filename" type="file">
<input class="mfuploadwp-submit" type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="form_id"/>
</form>
```

in php

```
switch($_POST['form_id']) {
   //the form data to be processed..
}
```

or

2. You can update the input field submit button naming based on the form number.

Eg:

```
Upload file: <input name="mfuploadwp-filename" type="file">
<input class="mfuploadwp-submit" type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit_{form_id}">
```

3. you can add a additional parameter in the form method.

   ...